# Repository test doesn't return expected number of entities

Tags: c#, unit-testing, repository-pattern, nunit-2.6.2

**Note >** The number of records in the Country Table: 36 records.

My code :

```
[TestFixture]
    public class CountriesControllerTest
    {
        Mock<IJN_CountryRepository> countryRepository;
        Mock<IUnitOfWork> unitOfWork;

        IJN_CountryService countryService;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            countryRepository = new Mock<IJN_CountryRepository>();
            unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
            countryService = new JN_CountryService(countryRepository.Object, unitOfWork.Object);
        }
        [Test]
        public void ManyDelete()
        {
            var count = countryService.GetCount();
            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(36, count);
        }
    }
```

NUnit Test Message :

[image]

Why? Why not read the number of records?

Answer (score 0):

With these two lines

```
countryRepository = new Mock<IJN_CountryRepository>();
unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
```

you created a *fake* objects, objects that have **no logic** nor any knowledge about any databases. These are [mocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object). You need to **instruct them what to do** in order to make them work, like:

```
var sampleCountries = Create36SampleCountries();
countryRepository = new Mock<IJN_CountryRepository>();
countryRepository.Setup(m => m.Countries).Returns(sampleCountries);
```

In order for your test to work with real database you should not be using mocks but your actual repositories (note that this would then be an integration test).